# Toggle Not Working With New Browsers

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net, browser, cross-browser

I'm working with a timesheet application that I'm having some problems with hiding/unhiding a panel using different browsers.  See screenshots.

Image 1: This is the general start page for what I'm doing.  Click on the button.

Image 2: This is the expected output.  It's the output I get in IE8.

Image 3: This is the output for the latest Chrome.  The panel is shown (improperly, notice it doesn't span the table, it's only one column wide) for a split second and hidden again.  I get the same result in the latest Firefox and IE.

[image: This is the general start page for what I'm doing. Click on the button.]
[image: This is the expected output. It's the output I get in IE8.]
[image: This is the output for the latest Chrome. The panel is shown (improperly) for a split second and hidden again. I get the same result in the latest Firefox.]

This is the Javascript for the toggling.

```
function toggleVisibility(panel)
{
    if (panel.style.display == "none")
    {
        panel.style.display = "";
    }
    else
    {
        panel.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

This is the aspx.cs calling the toggle

```
        TableCell showCell = new TableCell();
        HtmlButton showButton = new HtmlButton();
        showButton.Attributes.Add("onClick", "toggleVisibility(panel" +  timesheet.timesheetId.ToString() + ")");
        showCell.Controls.Add(showButton);

        TableCell nameCell = new TableCell();
        HyperLink nameLink = new HyperLink();
        nameLink.NavigateUrl = "./timesheet.aspx?timesheetId=" +  timesheet.timesheetId.ToString()+ "&empNum=" + timesheet.employeeId + "&PopUp=" + _approverEmployeeId;
        nameLink.Text = employeeName;
        nameLink.Target = "_blank";
        nameCell.Controls.Add(nameLink);
```

Further down in the aspx.cs file is where the panel is defined.

```
        TableRow childRow = new TableRow();
        TableCell childCell = new TableCell();
        childCell.ColumnSpan = headerRow.Cells.Count;
        childCell.Controls.Add(childTable);
        childRow.Controls.Add(childCell);
        childRow.Attributes.Add("Style", "Display: none");
        childRow.ID = "panel" + timesheet.timesheetId;

        summaryTable.Rows.Add(headerRow);
        summaryTable.Rows.Add(childRow);
```

When I remove *childRow.Attributes.Add("Style", "Display: none")*, the table is shown properly in all browsers.  Clicking on the button tied to toggle though it hides and then shows the table in the newer browsers.

Here's a snippet of the HTML. HTML for the entire page can be found here http://asalim.net/approval.txt.

```
    <table id="summaryTable" rules="all" bordercolor="Silver" border="1" style="border-color:Silver;border-style:None;height:32px;width:768px;Z-INDEX: 102; LEFT: 8px; POSITION: absolute; TOP: 136px">
    <tr>
        <td>Show Detail</td>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>EmployeeNumber</td>
        <td>Approved</td>
        <td>Reject</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="summary94458" style="border-color:Black;border-width:1px;border-style:Solid;">
        <td><button onClick="toggleVisibility(panel94458)"></button></td>
        <td><a href="./timesheet.aspx?timesheetId=94458&amp;empNum=051006&amp;PopUp=051006" target="_blank">XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</a></td>
        <td>051006</td>
        <td><input id="allApproved94458" type="checkbox" name="allApproved94458" onclick="approveLines(this, 94458);" /></td>
        <td><input type="submit" name="reject94458" value="Reject" onclick="window.open( './reject.aspx?empNum=051006&amp;timesheetId=94458');" language="javascript" id="reject94458" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="panel94458" style="Display: none">
        <td colspan="5"><table id="detailTable94458" bordercolor="Black" border="0" style="border-color:Black;border-width:1px;border-style:Solid;width:100%;">
            <tr>
                <td>Description</td>
                <td>Job</td>
                <td>Extra</td>
                <td>Cost Code</td>
                <td>Reg Hours</td>
                <td>OT Hours</td>
                <td>Mileage</td>
                <td>Approved</td>
            </tr>
```

Comment: Can you post some *minimal* HTML that shows the issue? The *toggleVisibilty* function looks fine. Perhaps test for "none" first, e.g. `panel.style.display = panel.style.display == 'none'? 'block' : 'none';`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. As i already mentioned for the display problem, use "table-row" when you want the element to be visible, not ""
2. For the disappearance problem, your button is causing your form to be submitted. There are two easy workaround options

   - Change your element to one without an associated action, such as span:
     `<span onClick="toggleVisibility(panel94458)">View</span>`
   - Prevent the default button action via javascript:
     `<button onClick="toggleVisibility(panel94458); return false;">View</button>`

Comment: Also worth notign that the "disappearing" problem was actually sending a lot of form submits to your server, so you may want to take a look into that to see if no erroneous data has been saved this way

Comment: The span option you mentioned is how I do things, and will probably sort the problem out.

Comment: I did the second option returning false and that did the trick.  Thanks Fabio.

Comment: @ASalim you dont really need to return false in the Onclick event. The reason it wasnt working in chrome was the 'type' attr of btn tag wasnt defined. thats the best practice.

Answer (score 3):

You should add type="button". Works in latest Chrome: http://test.dogaev.pp.ua/ Please inform when I can remove this page from my server

Comment: The problems been resolved Gennady.  You can remove the code.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Update the following:

```
<button onClick="toggleVisibility(panel94458)"></button>
```

to

```
<button onClick="javascript:toggleVisibility(panel94458);" type="button"></button>
```

As per http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_button.asp

> Tip: Always specify the type attribute for a  element.
>   Different browsers use different default types for the 
>   element.

Answer (score 0):

Are you use ASP.NET Web Forms? Which version?

If so, one reason it may not behave in modern browsers is that ASP.NET is not recognizing the browser properly, and defaulting to down-level response javascript and HTML.

(You may be able to verify that by saving the page source in different browsers and comparing.)

To help fix this, you need to update ASP.NET knowledge of browsers and their capabilities. Hopefully this link will get you sorted: http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/41420

Ensuring you're using a newer version of ASP.NET may also get it working for you.

Answer (score -1):

In `toggleVisibility`, try replacing `panel.style.display = "";` with `panel.style.display = "table-cell";`

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display

Comment: No go.  Weird thing is that it shows for a second in Chrome and then disappears.  The page also seems to reload.

Comment: Sorry, from the image, I had assumed that the "panel" was referring to a table cell, but looking at your code a bit more, it appears to be referring to the row. So use `"table-row"` instead. Either way, could you post a sample of the HTML code produced rather than the server-side source code.

Comment: Table-row solves the problem is that the summary table now spans fully across in Chrome like it does in IE.  However, I still have the visibility automatically toggling off.  The full HTML can be found here - http://asalim.net/approval.txt

Answer (score -1):

Try using '===' instead of '==', as follows :-

function toggleVisibility(panel)
{
    if (panel.style.display === "none")
    {
        panel.style.display = "";
    }
    else
    {
        panel.style.display = "none";
    }
}

It's a bit of a flyer, but this has messed me around before. I would also think setting it to blank, ie 'panel.style.display = "";' would cause a problem. Surely is should be 'block'?

Comment: Tried both options, the === and block and still no go.  I'm going to post the HTML that Fabio asked for in a minute.